# Furnace vent pipe on roof full of frost, fan won't push hot air

Tags: vent

After living in the same house for 7 years and having much more snow, my vent on the roof was full of frost. The thermostat would kick on,but no heat.

This is the second time in 2 mths I had the vent taken off and cleared of frost. Once the vent was cleared the problem was gone. An elbow was left instead of 2 elbows on a pipe that was previously attached.

I asked the tech what else it could be, and he said maybe a secondary burner.$5000 for a new furnace installed and vented through the side if the house and not the roof. Will wait

[image]

[image]

Vent removed from on roof
[[image]

[image]

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: The furnace tech said to cap the roof vents. Then run the pvc horizontally through the basement wall.(assuming l get a new furnace) Eventually l'd have a roofing company tear out the stack and pipes and re-shingle the roof. How do l know a secondary burner isn't the problem?

Comment: Joe search the site there are questions several from Canada where the temps of -30 and -40 the owners are having problems with horizontal systems freezing up.

Comment: Also, it appears that you may have created 2 accounts. Did you also ask [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/216158/34147)? If that is also your question, please [click here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on how to get the 2 accounts merged so you can properly earn magical internet points that will allow you to comment on other people's posts (among other _amazing_ features and benefits!)