# White Rogers 9600 Thermostat-Set at 70 Deg,dropped to 62 deg-no heat-Trane XR90 gas furnace

Tags: thermostat

[image][image: Thermostat]I checked the batteries on my White Rogers-9600 thermostat,which were fine.(earlier in the day-furnace ran fine)
At 12pm the thermostat dropped to 62 degrees with no heat. After kicking up the heat to 70.It worked fine till 6am.When the thermostat showed 62 degrees again,and the house was cold.I hit the reset button. Now the heat is staying at 70 ,but for how long,as only time will tell. The thermostat wasn't programmed.
Assuming the reset fixed the problem,why did l have the drop in temp w/o programming the thermostat?

[[image: Thermostat]

Answer (score 1):

There is default programming that somehow probably started running. Maybe somebody pressed "run schedule" or "use schedule" or "run program". If you set the t-stat to "permanent hold" and it still runs the schedule, it's probably a problem with the t-stat itself.

Found this nugget in the install manual for your t-stat. What intrigued me is the default of 62 degrees is what you were experiencing.   The times might be off, install manuals aren't always fully accurate.   EDIT:  just noticed the comment at the bottom of the snippet. 6:00 AM!  Sounds like the default program started running.

[image: default programming]

Comment: Is it possible when l replaced the batteries, the thermostat was at  62 deg. and somehow memorized the setting? I never hit the reset button after replacing the batteries.

Comment: Although l did hit reset this morn at 6am.Which seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I suspect the tstat defaulted to auto when you "checked the batteries". Did you take them out? how did you check them? Hard to know exactly how each tstat responds to the batteries being replaced but it wouldn't surprise me if it went into "auto" (run program) when the batteries were replaced. Glad you don't have a serious problem.